# python3-apt must be installed and visible from /usr/bin/python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, ansible

I upgraded python from 3.6 to 3.10 in Ubuntu18 as 3.6.9 is no longer being maintained

```
add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
apt install python3.10
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.10 100
update-alternatives --config
```

After upgrading to 3.10, Ansible no longer works and throwing python3-apt errors. Controller has Python3.10 installed. If I point back to 3.6, ansible works fine. Any thoughts?

```
(py310) foo:linux-ansible lchan$ ansible --version
ansible [core 2.13.4]
  config file = /Users/lchan/Documents/rgithub/linux-ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/Users/ka.chan/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ansible/6.4.0/libexec/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /Users/lchan/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /opt/homebrew/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.10.7 (main, Sep 14 2022, 22:38:23) [Clang 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.102)]
  jinja version = 3.1.2
  libyaml = True
```

```
...
<10.224.240.178> (1, b'\r\n{"failed": true, "msg": "python3-apt must be installed and visible from /usr/bin/python3.", "invocation": {"module_args": {"name": "screen", "package": ["screen"], "state": "present", "update_cache_retries": 5, "update_cache_retry_max_delay": 12, "cache_valid_time": 0, "purge": false, "force": false, "upgrade": "no", "dpkg_options": "force-confdef,force-confold", "autoremove": false, "autoclean": false, "fail_on_autoremove": false, "only_upgrade": false, "force_apt_get": false, "clean": false, "allow_unauthenticated": false, "allow_downgrade": false, "allow_change_held_packages": false, "lock_timeout": 60, "update_cache": null, "deb": null, "default_release": null, "install_recommends": null, "policy_rc_d": null}}}\r\n', b'Shared connection to 10.224.240.178 closed.\r\n')
<10.224.240.178> Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Shared connection to 10.224.240.178 closed.
<10.224.240.178> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ansible
<10.224.240.178> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'IdentityFile="/Users/ka.chan/.ssh/id_rsa_a"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="ansible"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o 'ControlPath="/Users/ka.chan/.ansible/cp/685a59c7b2"' 10.224.240.178 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'rm -f -r /tmp/ansible-tmp-1665473272.986658-20597-259347628112350/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'"'"''
<10.224.240.178> (0, b'', b'')
ams1-smokeping1 | FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "allow_change_held_packages": false,
            "allow_downgrade": false,
            "allow_unauthenticated": false,
            "autoclean": false,
            "autoremove": false,
            "cache_valid_time": 0,
            "clean": false,
            "deb": null,
            "default_release": null,
            "dpkg_options": "force-confdef,force-confold",
            "fail_on_autoremove": false,
            "force": false,
            "force_apt_get": false,
            "install_recommends": null,
            "lock_timeout": 60,
            "name": "screen",
            "only_upgrade": false,
            "package": [
                "screen"
            ],
            "policy_rc_d": null,
            "purge": false,
            "state": "present",
            "update_cache": null,
            "update_cache_retries": 5,
            "update_cache_retry_max_delay": 12,
            "upgrade": "no"
        }
    },
    "msg": "python3-apt must be installed and visible from /usr/bin/python3."
}
```

Comment: I faced same problem. how to solve this?